# Change footnotes' location in Jekyll

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

Can someone please tell me if this is possible and how to do it. I struggled almost all day and I really don't know what to do.

So I need to insert some text at the end of the article. A text stored in a variable lets say `site.data.settings.var`. So I did this

```
{{ content }} 
{{ site.data.settings.var }}
```

And everything is ok until I have a post with footnotes. They appear before my text. I have no idea what to do.

I thought I could access the footnotes like this `{{ post.footnotes }}`, but it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: How does your post layout look like, `_layouts/post.html`?

Comment: I need a bit of help to go ahead. Do you mean  a) The footnotes should be BETWEEN content and settings.var  b) The footnotes should be AFTER content and seetings.var?

Answer (score 0):

try in markdown the usage of `[^1]` or `[^My_Note]`

```markdown
myText[^1] ... lorem ipusm ... foo bar.

...

[^1]: My note as footnote
```

Then style the footnote via `css`.

> I will update my answer when I have seen the layout `post.html`. I was to fast with answering. You are able to set footnotes, but footnotes will break your design.